# How to prove the mutual equivalence of peirce, classic, excluded_middle, de_morgan_not_and_not and implies_to_or without using intuition in coq

Tags: logic, coq, proof, type-theory

I simplified the proof procedure of the mutual equivalence of peirce, classic, excluded_middle, de_morgan_not_and_not and implies_to_or primarily written in `git@github.com:B-Rich/sf.git` as following.

```
Theorem excluded_middle_irrefutable:  forall (P:Prop), ~ ~ (P \/ ~ P).
Proof.
  intros. unfold not. intros.
  apply H. right. intros. apply H. left. apply H0.
Qed.

Definition peirce                := forall P Q: Prop, ((P->Q)->P)->P.
Definition classic               := forall P :  Prop, ~~P -> P.
Definition excluded_middle       := forall P :  Prop, P \/ ~P.
Definition de_morgan_not_and_not := forall P Q: Prop, ~(~P /\ ~Q) -> P\/Q.
Definition implies_to_or         := forall P Q: Prop, (P->Q) -> (~P\/Q).

Theorem peirce_classic : peirce -> classic.
Proof.
  compute. intros.
  specialize (H P False).
  apply H. intros.
  apply H. contradiction H0.
Qed.

Theorem classic_excluded_middle : classic -> excluded_middle.
Proof.
  compute. intros.
  apply H. intros.
  apply H0.
  right.
  intros.
  assert (P \/ (P->False)) as H2.
    apply (or_introl H1).
  apply (H0 H2).
Qed.

Theorem false_dist_1 : forall {P Q : Prop}, (P \/ Q -> False) -> (P -> False) /\ (Q -> False).
Proof.
  intros.
  split.
  intros.
  apply (H (or_introl H0)).
  intros.
  apply (H (or_intror H0)).
Qed.

Theorem false_dist_2 : forall {P Q : Prop}, (P -> False) /\ (Q -> False) -> (P \/ Q -> False).
Proof.
  intros.
  inversion H.
  inversion H0.
  apply (H1 H3).
  apply (H2 H3).
Qed.

Theorem em_de_morgan : excluded_middle -> de_morgan_not_and_not.
Proof.
  compute. intros.
  specialize (H (P \/ Q)).
  inversion H.
  apply H1.
  apply (False_ind (P \/ Q) (H0 (false_dist_1 H1))).
Qed.

Theorem double_neg : forall P : Prop,
  P -> ((P->False)->False).
Proof.
  (* WORKED IN CLASS *)
  intros P H. intros G. apply G. apply H.  Qed.

Theorem de_morgan_to_or : de_morgan_not_and_not -> implies_to_or.
Proof.
  compute. intros.
  specialize (H (P -> False) Q).
  intuition.
Qed.

Theorem to_or_peirce: implies_to_or -> peirce.
Proof.
  compute. intros.
  specialize (H P P).
  intuition.
Qed.
```

I remove some `intuition` tactics successfully, except the last two.

My question is:

- How to prove to_or_peirce and de_morgan_to_or without using the `intuition` tactic?
- What does the `intuition` tactic do?
- Is there a way to extract the concrete procedures which might be generated by the `intuition` tactic?

Answer (score 1):

(First off, I know that this is part of [Benjamin C. Pierce's Software Foundations](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/sf/). These are used for university classes, so I will not give you solutions to these exercises and spoil the fun for everyone else. If you're doing these on your own (like I did), I'm sorry but I hope you can understand – I don't want to "reward" their effort to put these materials out in the open with extra work for coming up with new exercises.)

---

> Is there a way to extract the concrete procedures which might be generated by the `intuition` tactic?

Well, for any defined thing, you can do `Print thing.` to get the definition. For things that have been manually defined, that usually looks pretty much like what you wrote. For things generated by tactics, this can be seriously unreadable (and even contain unnecessary long-winded indirections.) With practice, you'll eventually be able to mostly read and re-construct (in a more readable way) the proofs of these.

What may or may not work is saying `info <tactic>`, which should output the list/tree of applied tactics – but it seems to be broken (for years by now…), in new versions of Coq there may be specialized tactics like  `info_trivial`, `info_auto`, or `info_eauto` that *might* help you.

---

> What does the intuition tactic do?

The [documentation of `intuition`](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/Reference-Manual010.html#hevea_tactic147) is rather cryptic, but contains the helpful snippets

> […] In fact, `tauto` is simply `intuition fail`.
>
> […]
>
> Variants:
>
> 1. `intuition`
>        Is equivalent to `intuition auto with *`.

(That last part means you could try `intuition info_auto` and see if that gives you any useful info. Unfortunately, it'll just print a long list of `(* info auto : *) idtac.` because these theorems are all tautologies and `auto` doesn't do anything.)

So, on to the [documentation of `tauto`](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/Reference-Manual010.html#hevea_tactic146):

> This tactic implements a decision procedure for intuitionistic propositional calculus based on the contraction-free sequent calculi LJT* of Roy Dyckhoff [[54](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/biblio.html#Dyc92)]. Note that `tauto` succeeds on any instance of an intuitionistic tautological proposition. `tauto` unfolds negations and logical equivalence but does not unfold any other definition.

That should be perfectly clear now, right? Right? ;-)

(At that point, you could try looking at [the *definition* of `tauto`](https://github.com/coq/coq/blob/2206b405c19940ca4ded2179d371c21fd13f1b6b/tactics/tauto.ml4) but that's also not much clearer.)

Putting the pieces together and giving examples:

As the documentation says, `tauto` (and hence `intuition`) "implement a decision procedure for intuitionistic propositional calculus".  That is, anything that's just "reordering of stuff" in conjunctions (`/\`), disjunctions (`\/`), (bi)implications (`<->`/`->`) and some cases of negation (`~`) should be solved by this.

```
Variables A B C D : Prop.
Lemma foo : (A /\ B) -> A.  tauto.  Qed.            (* solves *)
Lemma bar : (A /\ B) -> A.  auto. (* fails *) auto 9999 with *. (* fails *)
Lemma baz : ((B /\ C) /\ D) -> ((A /\ C) -> (D /\ B /\ (A /\ A))).
            tauto.  Qed.  (* solves *)
Lemma qux : (A \/ B) /\ (C \/ (A -> B)) /\ ~B -> C.  tauto.  Qed. (* solves *)
(* etc. *)
```

For all of these, `auto` will do nothing but `tauto` ("tautology") will immediately solve them. `intuition` will simply try to do some more things when the basic taking-apart and throwing-together of `tauto` is done and didn't solve everything yet.

(Does that help?)

---

> How to prove `to_or_peirce` and `de_morgan_to_or` without using the `intuition` tactic?

A hint: Your `H` has the form `… -> (… \/ …)`, you can `destruct` or `case` analyze it, as you'd do with a disjunction (but in this "sea of symbols" it may be hard to see that this is possible).  The rest should be fairly easy.